# Unified reporter/formatter for ESLint/Plato/Mocha/Istanbul

Tags: javascript

I'm using ESLint, Plato, Mocha and Istanbul to check and test the code quality and run tests.

For now, each tool uses its own reporter or formatter:

- ESLint: built-in html formatter
- Plato: default output
- Mocha: mochawesome
- Istanbul: default output

Each reporter or formatter is good but I'd like to see them in a more unified/integrated page.

Is there any good reporter/formatter which supports these tools?

Maybe I can collect all raw results and build my own page, but if there is any good option, I'd like to use it.